# How can I make the "R" key only rotate the object around the x & y axis?

Tags: customization, shortcut

I have managed to make a change so that the the default rotate function for "R" (free) gets locked around the Z axis when in the perspective viewport. The problem is that when I do that Blender will not rotate around the correct axis when you enter the left, right, top viewports etc. Is there any way to keep Blenders' default on all viewports except the perspective one?

Comment: What if you use a different key for your customized locking rotation, and keep R as the default?

Comment: It seems like a backwards sollution, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Wait a few minutes, I'll write this addon for you

Comment: On second thought, this was harder than I thought (misunderstood your question). Might do it later today tho.

Comment: Thank you that would be great! did you read what sambler wrote aswell?

Answer (score 3):

When you press <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate the object, press either <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>Z</kbd> on your keyboard. That will allow you to only rotate on one axis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i already know that. The reason why i wanted to change this is that i don't have to press the x,y,z ever time.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Blender doesn't offer the options you want but I expect you can achieve this with an addon.

By creating your own rotation operator you can look at various properties then choose which options to set when calling the existing rotation operator. Then you replace the key-binding to run your operator instead of the standard operator.

Comment: Thanks! I am not skilled enought to code this but its great to know that it can be done!